# SignalR & require.js configuration

Tags: javascript, requirejs, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm incorporating **SignalR** into a project where I'm already using **require.js** to handle my scripts dependencies.

I'm having a little trouble making sure "/signalr/hubs" is called after "jquery.signalR-1.1.2" loads.

I got it to work, but I'm wondering if there is a better alternative out there.

This is what I have:

```
require(["signalr"], function () {
  require(["noext!/signalr/hubs"], function () {
      //initialize and work with the hub here
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can create a shim here to establish the dependency between signalr/hubs and the signalr script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This works for me with SignalR 1.1.2:

```js
require.config({
baseUrl: "/<your scripts dir>",
paths: {
    "jquery": "jquery-<your jquery version>.min",
    "signalr.core": "jquery.signalR-<your signalr version>.min",
    "signalr.hubs": "/signalr/hubs?"
},
shim: {
    "jquery": {
        exports: "$"
    },
    "signalr.core": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "$.connection"
    },
    "signalr.hubs": {
        deps: ["signalr.core"],
    }
}
});

require(["jquery", "signalr.hubs"],
    function($)
    {
        var hubProxy = $.connection.myHub;

        // ... go to town ...
    });
```

Comment: Hi Drew,
Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried that, and this is what I get:

GET http://localhost:39047/scripts/noext!/signalr/hubs.js?v=635092295003095722 404 (Not Found) require.js:1854
Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:159

Comment: While it makes perfect sense in theory, it is not working in practice. Not sure why, really frustrating.

Comment: Just want to check, do you actually have /scripts/noext.js in your project??

Comment: Updated answer after throwing together a sample. Totally works for me now. I don't even use the noext plugin, just throw a query string marker on the end and require.js won't mess with it.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that noext was the culprit here.

Comment: Yeah, there's a way to do it, but you can't create a friendly name with noext. I found it easier/cleaner just to short circuit the regular .js suffixing rules with the empty query string.